# vuetify3 v-radio is transparent

Tags: vue.js, radio-button, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Vuetify3 is now out, so I started using v-radio wrapped by v-radio-group.
v-radio itself is working properly, but the problem is that radio buttons are somehow transparent. Even if I change the color of the radio buttons, that changes the color of them only when they are hovered.

The screenshot below shows the situation, and on the left side of "hello", there are transparent radio buttons.

[image]
I would like to know how to fix this problem. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<v-radio-group v-model="secondKw" inline class="ma-1">
   <v-radio
      v-for="kw in keywords"
      :label="kw"
      :value="kw"
      v-bind:key="kw"
   ></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

Even if I try the sample code on the website. They are transparent. Is there any possible explanation for this? Other style is adopted to this project.

Comment: Even if I try the sample code on the website. They are transparent. Is there any possible explanation for this? Other style is adopted to this project.

Answer (score 1):

You probably figured it out by now, but anyway:

This usually happens when you have not installed any icon font, i.e. Material Design Icons or Font Awesome.

Compare the two snippets, first one doesn't have icons, second one does:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
createApp({}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.4/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<div id="app" class="d-flex justify-center">
  <v-app>
    <v-checkbox label="checkbox without icons"/>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
createApp({}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app" class="d-flex justify-center">
  <v-app>
    <v-checkbox label="checkbox with icons"/>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

The [documentation for icon fonts](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/) will provide more details.